# How can I prove that E[X + Y |X,Y ] = E[X|Y ] + E[Y |X]?

Tags: probability-theory, conditional-expectation

I feel like this function is not right but I can not prove whether it is right or wrong. Could anyone give a hand explaining why it is right or why it is wrong?

Comment: Take $X,Y$ i.i.d. $N(0,1)$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your identity is false (e.g. consider $X,Y$ independent). Whatever is conditioned on is fixed so

$$E[X+Y|X,Y]=X+Y.$$

Comment: So in this way this identity will never be true am I understanding it right? Like if X and Y are independent then the right side should be E(x)+E(y) which should be different from X+Y?

Comment: The equation you wrote is false, and yes, $X,Y$ independent is a counterexample

Comment: Got it, thank you so much!

Comment: no prob, feel free to accept the answer if it helps